# Undefined references when linking with gcc -lnetsnmp

Tags: linux, gcc, openssl, raspberry-pi, snmp

I'm trying to compile and run my code on a raspberry pi which needs the snmp libraries. However, I get linking errors such as "undefined reference to 'EVP_DigestUpdate'".

I've been researching this issue for the past few days and found out that this usually happens when snmp can't find the ssl library crypto, for example if you don't specify -lcrypto before -lsnmp when linking your object, or when the linker just can't can't find -lcrypto.

However, on my raspberry pi I have all required libraries in /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf.

This is how I installed the libraries:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libsnmp-dev libsnmp-base libsnmp30
```

I generate trap.o with this command:

```
gcc -c -g -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -I/home/pi/tests/h -I/usr/include trap.c -o trap.o
```

I link trap.o the libraries with this command:

```
gcc -static -g -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow trap.o -o trap -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -lcrypto -lpthread -lnetsnmpagent -lnetsnmpmibs -lnetsnmphelpers -lnetsnmp
```

And then I get this error:

```
    gcc -static -g -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow trap.o -o trap -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -lcrypto -lpthread -lnetsnmpagent -lnetsnmpmibs -lnetsnmphelpers -lnetsnmp
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_str_to_gid':
(.text+0x1144): warning: Using 'getgrnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_str_to_gid':
(.text+0x1154): warning: Using 'endgrent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_str_to_uid':
(.text+0x10d8): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_str_to_uid':
(.text+0x10e8): warning: Using 'endpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_getaddrinfo':
(.text+0x4a4): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): In function `netsnmp_gethostbyaddr':
(.text+0x9f8): warning: Using 'gethostbyaddr' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
trap.o: In function `parse_address':
/home/pi/tests/trap.c:56: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/glibc-6f8a9a/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119: undefined reference to `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_random':
(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_generate_keyed_hash':
(.text+0x290): undefined reference to `EVP_md5'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_generate_keyed_hash':
(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `HMAC'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_generate_keyed_hash':
(.text+0x33c): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x438): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x448): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x468): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_hash':
(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `EVP_md5'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0x86c): undefined reference to `DES_key_sched'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0x8a0): undefined reference to `DES_ncbc_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0x8c4): undefined reference to `DES_ncbc_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0x90c): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0x948): undefined reference to `AES_cfb128_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0xa74): undefined reference to `DES_key_sched'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_encrypt':
(.text+0xaac): undefined reference to `DES_ncbc_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_decrypt':
(.text+0xc78): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_decrypt':
(.text+0xcb0): undefined reference to `AES_cfb128_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_decrypt':
(.text+0xd9c): undefined reference to `DES_key_sched'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(scapi.o): In function `sc_decrypt':
(.text+0xdd0): undefined reference to `DES_cbc_encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `EVP_md5'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnetsnmp.a(keytools.o): In function `generate_Ku':
(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could it be that the issue is being caused because the snmp libraries I installed were built using a different openssl version than the ones I have in my environment? My libssl-dev and libsnmp-dev versions are the following:

dpkg -l | grep libssl-dev:

```
ii  libssl-dev:armhf                      1.0.1k-3+deb8u5                           armhf        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
```

dpkg -l | grep libsnmp-dev:

```
ii  libsnmp-dev                           5.7.2.1+dfsg-1                            armhf        SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) development files
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your undefined references are in `libnetsnmp` and they are all undefined
references to functions defined in `libcypto`. This happens because `-lcrypto`
precedes `-lnetsnmp` in your linkage.

In the linkage sequence, files that need symbol definitions must occur
before the ones that provide the definitions, because the linker by default will
only search a library to find definitions of symbols that it has
observed to be referenced, but not defined, in earlier files. (You appear to
have mis-learned this rule, the wrong way round). From `man ld`:

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where
>   it is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a
>   symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the
>   archive on the command line, the linker will include the
>   appropriate file(s) from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol
>   in an object appearing later on the command line will not cause the
>   linker to search the archive again.

So link `-lcrypto` after `-lnetsnmp`.

Comment: You're right! I also had to link -ldl after -lcrypto to get it working. Now I'm only getting warnings such as: "using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking". Would that be something to be concerned about?